# ctags follow custom shebang

Tags: bash, sh, ctags, exuberant-ctags

i crated a shell script which uses a custom shebang.

```
#!/usr/bin/env my_custom_shebang

bash_function() {

}
```

i want ctags to generate a tags file for the language bash for it.

i tried `ctags -R my-custom-script --force-language=sh` without success.

if i change `#!/usr/bin/env my_custom_shebang` to `#!/usr/bin/env bash` ctags is doing fine.

But i need ctags to generate the tags with having my instead of the bash shebang in the first line.

can someone help me out here?

Answer (score 0):

You have several options.

`--language-force=sh` is the simplest one. The one you tried, `--force-language=sh`, does not exist.

Another option would be using a custom extension (say, `.cst`) and the option `--langmap=sh:+.cst`.

If you see `+wildcards` in the output of `ctags --version`, you can also use filename patterns enclosed in parentheses instead of a custom extension, i.e., you call all your `my_custom_shebang` scripts with a name beginning with `cst_` and you can use `--langmap='sh:+(cst_*)'`.

As a final note, it is my understanding that the jargon term *shebang* refers to the two characters `#!`, and by extension to the whole line beginning with them, and not to the particular command interpreter being invoked. So I’d rephrase your example of a custom shebang as

```
#!/usr/bin/env my_custom_interpreter
```

but this is really a pedantic remark.

Answer (score 0):

My answer assumes you are using universal-ctags (https://ctags.io).

I will show two different solutions.

A. Changing the order of options

Try

```
ctags --force-language=sh -R my-custom-script
```

instead of

```
ctags -R my-custom-script --force-language=sh
```

.

B. Use --alias-=+ option

Try

```
ctags --alias-sh=my-custom-script -R my-custom-script
```

.

Answer (score 0):

I've found this option working for me and shell (bash) scripts parsed correctly:

```
--guess-language-eagerly
```

Note: I'm using Universal Ctags.

Source: https://github.com/universal-ctags/ctags/issues/1261

To parse variables I'm additionaly use:

```
--regex-sh=/^[ \t]*(local|export)?[ \t]*([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)=/\2/v,variable,variables/
```